# MVC 5 Data Annotations Remote Model List

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, model, data-annotations

I have inherited a project, where there the form has several section as well as several models.  One section/model has: Name, Address, BirthDate (DOB), etc.  A user can fill that out, then click the "Add" button to add another member of the family.  The fields, after clicking "Add" are identical in appearance.  It also uses the same model (why not!).  This currently works fine!

The issue #1, no validation of the input date, so a user could enter 13/12/8500 (mm/dd/yyyy), so naturally I had to add a validation on the BirthDate (DOB) field.  #1 somewhat solved:

** Code Model

```
[DataType(DataType.DateTime, ErrorMessage = "Invalid Date")]
[Display(Name = "Birth Date (mm/dd/yyyy format):")]
[DisplayFormat(ApplyFormatInEditMode = true, DataFormatString = "{0:MM/dd/yyyy}")]
[Remote("IsValidDateOfBirth", "AML", HttpMethod = "POST", ErrorMessage = "Please provide a valid date of birth.")]
public DateTime? DOB { get; set; }
```

** Code Controller

```
[HttpPost]
public JsonResult IsValidDateOfBirth([Bind(Prefix = "setlList[0].DOB")]string DOB)
{
    var min = DateTime.Now.AddYears(-200);
    var max = DateTime.Now;
    var msg = string.Format("Please enter a value between {0:MM/dd/yyyy} and {1:MM/dd/yyyy}", min, max);
    try
    {
        var date = DateTime.Parse(DOB);
        if (date > max)
            return Json(string.Format("Date can't be greater than {0:MM/dd/yyyy}", max));
        else if (date < min)
            return Json(string.Format("Date should be greater than {0:MM/dd/yyyy}", min));              
        else
            return Json(true);
    }
    catch (Exception)
    {
        return Json(msg);
    }
}
```

The above implementation works fine for the first/initial BirthDate!  Yeah baby!

I hit the "Add" to add another member, so far so good, but when I put in a Birthday - Bamm Issue #2 occurs.  The *IsValidDateOfBirth* IS called for the 2nd BirthDate but a **null** is passed to the validator.

I believe it has to do with the binding in the validator (*([Bind(Prefix = "setlList[0].DOB")]*), I tried to remove the binding, but that didn't work (null was being passed 100% of the time).  I tried to shorten to *Prefix=setList*, **surprise** - that didn't work either.

I keep scratching my head on HOW to accomplish this.  I thought of having multiple validator methods (which seem very silly) but this wouldn't work; due to using the same Model (not need to create multiple models either).

I must be missing something here?? 
*Yes, using jQuery 2.1.4, jQuery Validation Plugin 1.11.1, and jQuery unobtrusive*

Comment: _I must be missing something here?_ - Yes YOUR CODE! (links to images of it are not acceptable). And you certainly do not need a `RemoteAttribute` to validate a OB property (that can be done with conditional attributes)

Comment: Added code verses the links.

Comment: A `RemoteAttribute` is not necessary (and are you really expecting 1 day old babies and 200 year olds :) Far easier to use a conditional attribute, for example a [foolproof](http://foolproof.codeplex.com/) `[GreaterThan]` or similar attribute. Also [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27513472/remote-validation-for-list-of-models/27517407#27517407) explains the issue.

Comment: Note also that a `RemoteAttribute` is client side validation only and you need to repeat all that code again in the POST method (anyone can easily by-pass client side validation).

Comment: The best approach would be to create your own validation attribute - refer [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3309689/anyone-got-a-date-of-birth-validation-attribute-for-c-sharp-mvc) for an example (not a great one but its a starting point). Then you can also add client side validation by implementing `IClientValidatable` - refer [The Complete Guide To Validation In ASP.NET MVC 3 - Part 2](http://www.devtrends.co.uk/blog/the-complete-guide-to-validation-in-asp.net-mvc-3-part-2)

Comment: Thanks Stephen Muecke, yes there was validation prior to the DB save but that was it.  Yes, the parameters for a birthdate are more of an example, thanks.  The  [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27513472/remote-validation-for-list-of-models/27517407#27517407) resolved the issue perfectly.  Many thanks for your dedication!